# Return a list of words on a line but ignore certain whitespace

Tags: python, string

Say I have the line:

```
235Carling             Robert         140 Simpson Ave     Toronto        Ont M6T9H1416/247-2538416/889-6178
```

You see each collections of characters there? I want those to represent a column in a data file. The problem I'm having is for the "Street Address" column.

```
for i in master_file:
    #returns a list of the words, splitting at whitespace
    columns = i.split()
```

The problem is though this will split up `140 Simpson Ave` into three "words". Is there a method I can use to say only separate if the words are surrounded by a certain amount of whitespace or something?

Comment: Are your fields separated by tabs? If so you can use i.split("\t")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have tabs, this is pretty trivial, but if you're just looking for something where there's more than one space, you can use python's `re.split` method to do this:

```
import re

re.split('\s{2,}', '235Carling             Robert         140 Simpson Ave     Toronto        Ont M6T9H1416/247-2538416/889-6178')

['235Carling', 'Robert', '140 Simpson Ave', 'Toronto', 'Ont M6T9H1416/247-2538416/889-6178']
```

Where `\s{2,}` just matches any series of 2 or more whitespace characters.

If the characters between your rows there are actually tabs you can avoid the regex alltogether:

```
test = '235Carling             Robert         140 Simpson Ave     Toronto        Ont M6T9H1416/247-2538416/889-6178'

test.split('\t')

['235Carling', 'Robert', '140 Simpson Ave', 'Toronto', 'Ont M6T9H1416/247-2538416/889-6178']
```

Comment: Yep mine was the second case! How does that work exactly? Why does `split()` still seperate them as it normally would by default, but slightly different?

Comment: @Amon The default token for split is a space character, so when you use `split()`, really imagine it as `split(" ")`

Comment: Crap, I don't think I gave you all the details. I want a list where each field is a seperate element. This returns a list with only one element

Comment: @Amon It does? Because the above code works both if it's a series of spaces and if it's a tab character.

Comment: Yea, this is my output: `['235Carling             Robert         140 Simpson Ave     Toronto        Ont M6T9H1416/247-2538416/889-6178']`

Comment: @Amon for the first version, or the second version?

Comment: My bad, the second version is doing that

Comment: @Amon Awesome! Glad to hear it. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Whoops I meant the first one worked, the second one is still giving the same output

Comment: @Amon, yea the second one would only work if there were actually tab characters, and it seems that there are not.